# Error while comparing two dates

Tags: objective-c

```
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
 NSDate *staticDate = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2014-07-12"];

 NSComparisonResult result;

 result = [today compare:staticDate];

 if(result == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        self.t1.text = @"hello";
    }
```

I'm trying to compare a date with the current date but i'm having an error with dateWithString method it says "No known class method for dateWithString:"

Comment: That would be because NSDate has no method `dateWithString`.

Comment: `dateWithString:` is only on OSX, not iOS.

Comment: Keep in mind that the date comparison will be done down to the millisecond. Your two `NSDate` objects will never be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because `NSDate` has no method `dateWithString`. I think you can better use a `NSDateFormatter` instance for this

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Instances of NSDateFormatter create string representations of NSDate
>   (and NSCalendarDate) objects, and convert textual representations of
>   dates and times into NSDate objects.

Example:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@", strDate);
```

Comment: this will give me the current date or will allow me to add a static date to compare with the current date ?